# Che senso ha la parola "già" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, single-words

Ho trovato questa [domanda con risposta su Quora](https://it.quora.com/Che-senso-ha-la-vita-se-tanto-poi-moriamo) dove ci sono il nome dell'autore e le sue qualifiche. Volevo sapere che senso ha la parola *già* in questo contesto:

> Bartolomeo Antonio Scalzi, già Educatore presso Associazione Salam (2018)

Cosa significa *già*? Era? È? È ancora?

Answer (score 9):

In questo contesto significa che è stato educatore in quell'associazione, ma che ora non lo è più. 
[Dalla definizione del Treccani:](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/gia/)

> Davanti a un sostantivo, e sottintendendo i verbi essere o chiamarsi,
>   indica che la persona o la cosa nominata non esercita più
>   quell’ufficio, non ha più quella funzione o quel nome: il ministro
>   della Difesa, già sottosegretario agli Interni; il castello, già
>   residenza della famiglia reale; l’albergo delle Chiavi d’oro, già
>   «Locanda della Posta».

Capita spesso di trovare *già* usato in quest'accezione nei cartelli di vie o località che hanno cambiato nome

> via Tizio  (già via Caio)

Comment: Si può trovare anche di fronte a numeri civici in seguito ad un riordinamento degli stessi e.g. 159 (già 153)